# json: Can we avoid writing null properties while serializing objects (can we use @JsonWriteNullProperties(false) for this)?

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, jackson, gson

I'm trying to convert a json object `restFBResponse` to an object of class `Post` from Facebook graph-api.

```
MyPost post = gson.fromJson(restFBResponse.toString(), MyPost.class);
```

where, MyPost class is as follows:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonWriteNullProperties;

@JsonWriteNullProperties(false)
public class MyPost extends Post {

}
```

There are many fields in `Post` class. If any of those fields (say e.g. `actions`) is absent in json object `restFBResponse` then corresponding entry in object `post` will be null. But in class `Post`, actions is assigned with an arraylist by,

```
List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
```

So if `actions` is absent in `restFBResponse`, the `actions` field in `post` object will become `null`. And if I try to access actions to add new element by:

```
post.getActions().add(element)
```

it's resulting into error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Instead I want it to remain as `ArrayList<Action>` whenever `actions` is absent in `restFBResponse`. i.e. avoid writing if field is null `null`.

How can I acheive this?

I tried using `@JsonWriteNullProperties(false)` over all classes but still the result is same, i.e. absent elements in `restFBResponse` object have corresponding null entry in `post` object.

Comment: One solution would be to modify your `getActions` method to initialize the list if it null, prior to returning the value.

Comment: What if it's third party library, like `Post` from `Facebook-graph-api`?

Comment: If its a third party class you should definitely be doing null checks on returned data.

Comment: Are you mixing Gson with Jackson? You seem to be using the Gson api but with Jackson annotations???

Comment: yes.. will there be any problem? without Jackson annotation how can I achieve requirement of writing only non-null elements?